# tableView UPDATING all cells instead of only one

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have created a custom tableCell to design my cells. What i'm trying is to make **willDisplayCell** to change alpha value of the cells and i'm doing it like that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(ChatTableCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cell.alpha = 0.3;

    });



}
```

The problem here is that every time i add a new cell all the other cells alpha value reset and all new cells + old cells get changed at the same time. Please help me to update every cell and not letting it reset the alpha of old cells, becouse we add new cell.

**what i'm doing:**
Every cell created should change from full alpha to 0.3 after 3 seconds, but what happens is that the cells that have been created and have changed to  0.3 alpha get rested to full alpha again when i add more cells...

Comment: You are trying to set alpha for all the cells that will display. Try resetting the alpha value of all the visible cells then set specific cell alpha, but if you clear what you want to achieve I can help you better.

Comment: " Every cell created should change from full alpha to 0.3 after 3 seconds, but what happens is that the cells which is created and have changed to  0.3  alpha get rested to full alpha again... "  i'm trying to avoid that

Comment: Are you setting the cell's alpha also at another place? Because when I tried what you did I get the behavior that you want. Only new cells appear with alpha 1 and get 0.3 after 3 seconds. The old cells stay at 0.3

Comment: I call [_tableView reloadData]; on every new cell, do you think  its the problem and can you post a code to look at please

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

                if (cell == nil)
                {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
                }
                //if you are adding the item at the and of your array do this otherwise change the code in the if line

                if(indexPath.row == array.count - 1){
                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    cell.alpha = 0.3;

                });
            }
```

Comment: every time i call ll [_tableView reloadData]; it get called again

Comment: Check the alpha in the cellForRowAtIndexPath also!

Comment: Sorry for making it very hard, but could you please show me a full simple with that, i really appreciate you taking the time out, but example with that so i can follow it and understand it please

Comment: When you call [_tableView reloadData]; all the cells get called and if the alpha is full in storyboard settings then it will become full in your app too.
Try making everything in the cellForRow, I will update the answer.

Comment: I will try that out, test it and get back to you. Thanks alot for helping me Arben!

Comment: Okay my friend putting the code inside only cellForRow did not change anything. I'm loading my cell desigen from nib file.. can you guide me more if possible??